# Playing external video(HTTP) on krpano

Tags: http, krpano

I have been testing the video player of krpano for 360 videos that are stored locally and they work fine. But when I want to play a remote video over http (even a local server), the player doesn't play.

I have looked a lot regarding this problem, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also use krpano to play videos in my site.  If you want to play a remote video, you should set the request header attr: Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

But this doesn't work in Safari. So I am also looking for the solutions.